# Loading unfinished data to data warehouse

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

The title might be confusing so I'd like to present my current problem.

Please image the following situation: System stores devices' issues, which should be fixed by qualified workers. I have table "issue" with:

- id as PK
- workerid FK
- status which desribes whether the problem is solved or unsolved
- estimated completion time
- real completion time

and other columns. I have also a data warehouse which will store the "issues" and describe performance of those "workers" (working time mostly).

During the ETL process the biggest problem comes with "unsolved issues". I might have two possibilities:

a) process only solved "issues", leave unsolved until they are finished then wait until they are finished and process them. This task however will not include in my reports issues, that might take too long to finish, which might be crucial in business aspect.

b) process both solved and unsolved issues, the PK in Fact table could be issueId and status. But then i'll store almost identical issues which might be weird, and difficult to analize.

Is this common situation? Which of these two possibilities seems more reasonable? Or probably there is other, better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there should be an issues dimension, and that dimension would hold the status column. There are a couple of issues with changing facts:

1. You are going to have to setup a scheduled process that updates the status column of the fact table every x minutes. I always try to avoid updating a fact table, as it makes cube processing more difficult, it can introduce blocking, and change tracking is difficult (when did the status change, who changed it, and why?). Additionally, if/when you upgrade to SQL 2012 and want to use column-store indexes (which have revolutionized star schema query performance), you won't be able to directly update the column.
2. Dimensions are sometimes expected to change. Facts are not. If the status is in the dimension, it's also easy to set up change tracking. Look into slowly changing dimensions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

To get this thing straight: if I consider to store Status column inside Issue dimension should I update status or rather store additional issue with the same Id but with other status? Then i could use composite key (Id, status).  Which is better in your opinion? Because updating fact table doesn't seem like a good idea :)

Comment: @shaqqy - see my answer in your other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261827/one-to-one-relationship-in-data-warehouse) about this. You most certainly can update a fact table, as long as it's what's known as an "Accumulating Snapshot" fact, which is often used for workflow tracking such as this.

Comment: I didn't say you couldn't. I said "I always try to avoid updating a fact table". With the shift in big data DW industry trends moving from row-stores to column-stores (all big dw dbms' are moving in this direction, not just sql server), you'll find updating facts to be less scalable and more burdensome down the road. My opinion is that the fact table should be almost entirely insert only, even if that means using offsetting transactions to accomplish. Fact tables are too large for this level of complication. Avoid changing facts. My $0.02.

Comment: @brian I understood your concept and I completely agree with you about updating fact tables. I also try to avoid this but in order to solve my problem i'll be probably forced to update facts. +1 for you :)

@ N West +1 for you too, your answer was very helpful!