# One to one relationship in data warehouse

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence

Simple scenario: I'd like to create data warehouse which information about "issues" (cost, wroking time etc.). issue also has status which  might change over time. So then i'm creating fact table called issueRealization decribing each issue.

My question is: should i create "issue" dimension which will give me one to one relationship beetwen dimension and fact table? Or i should divide Issue dimension to smallest dimension like status etc?

Comment: Depends, are you re-using records in issueRealization or would you want to cascade deletion of issues to table issueRealization?

Comment: I will vote for snowflake schema....

Comment: @Neil No, i dont want to delete anything from the fact table. I just want to analize data with the current status of the issue. The problem is with storing this data.

Comment: Are there many facts for each issue type? Sounds like you need a fact which gives you a measure like COUNT, set to value 1, along with all the other measure like Hours_Open, Work_Expended_Hours etc, a dimension called Dim_Issue, which gives you a list of all possible issues and a dimension called Dim_Issue_Status. You may have a fact per unique issue per status it has been in, or just 1 fact with the latest status, maybe with measures like Hours_In_Pending_Status, Hours_In_Progress etc.

Comment: @Steve Thank you for your reply but i have to go further with my problem :) Lets say i'll take your idea and add to my FactIssueRealization table sequence which determines issue's latest status. Would't it be quite difficult to query in MDX in case i'd like to choose issue with the highest sequence (latest status).

I thought the best idea was to establish in Fact table issueid + status as primary key and FK ath the same time, create issue table with issueid + status as PK and update issue table. But then i'd have one to one relationship. Is this solution ok?

Comment: Maybe add a Current Status flag to the fact - filter this to yes to see how things are now, or not filter it to see the history also.  You need to know when the issue passed to each status to calculate how long the issue spent in each status.  You might want to store a record per issue per status (granular) and then build an aggregate fact which has 1 row per issue, with measures storing how long it spent in each status - not all of these will have values unless it is now resolved, and a current status dimension.

Comment: Realise I've missed some of your point.  There are two things, an instance of an issue, and a description of an issue.  The instance of an issue is a fact, and counts as 1 in a count query.  The description of an issue should be in a dimension called Dim_Issue_Type, and only the surrogate key from this dimension should be stored in the fact, not the description itself.  I assume the same issue type has many instances?

Comment: @Steve So you suggest i should create additional table (fact table?) to store record per issue per status and transfer from this table only the latest issues to the actual fact table?
Issue can have two instances in fact table: solved and not solved.
Well my point was that i didn't know if i can create one to one rel. in DW or try to use only many to many. Also i had problem with status which determines which data is actual, and how to select this actual data.

Comment: Is the issue description free text, or do users pick the issue description from a list?  Are you saying there are only 2 statuses, unsolved and solved?  There's nothing in principle wrong with having a dimension with a one-to-one relationship with a fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue status tracking is a good case to use an **Accumulating Snapshot** fact table, to track the changes in the status of an issue over time.

As an example, let's say this is an IT issue/bug/enhancement management system, with issues that only have 3 statuses, 'Created' and 'In Progress' and 'Resolved'.

The issue fact table would look like such:

```
ID Number (Degenerate Dimension)
Issue description (Degenerate dimension. You can also create a 1-1 table for these if it's not often used in reporting)
Type ID (bug/enhancement/etc, this is a dimension key)
Assigned Developer ID (Dimension key)
Current Status ID (Status dimension key)
Date Created (DATE dimension)
Created Flag (1 = created, 0 = otherwise)
Date In Progress (DATE dimension)
In Progress Flag (1 = created, 0 = otherwise)
Date Resolved (DATE dimension)
Resolved Flag (1 = created, 0 = otherwise)
Created Datetime (measure)
InProgress Datetime (measure)
Resolved Datetime (measure)
Worktime Interval (measure)
Cost (measure)
```

The grain of this table is 1 row per issue ID number.

With this type of fact table, you update the *same row* each time the source system modifies an issue. Note how we create a field for each status type, as well as a datetime record to allow us to compute metrics such as "time between created and resolved status". In addition, I added an interval field to allow you to store "actual" work time, such as "hours" the developer put towards the fix. This could easily be an integer.

This table would then be able to answer any questions about an issue, and provide rollups to show "how many issues took longer than 1 week to resolve", etc.

Comment: @N West This is really interesting design! But instead of creating column for each status type inside fact table, can I create junk dimension DimStatusIssue with status column only, which stores each status type and connect it to fact via FK?

Comment: @shaqqy - that's already on the fact table as the "Current Status ID" key which would link to the Issue Status dimension. The idea behind the accumulating snapshot is you want to track the workflow as it moves from one status to the next. If you don't need to track the workflow, you don't have to include the additional columns, but then you lose the ability to see the history of each fact row.

Comment: @N West And should I update fact table directly after status is changed? (Something like trigger)

Comment: I would not use triggers. Changes to the Accumulating Snapshot should be done as part of your ETL process.

Comment: One last question if I may :) Do I need to use flags in Accumulating Snapshot? Looks like "Current Status ID" is enough...

Comment: I like flags because they can be easily summed, rather than trying to do counts and joining against the status table. If, for example, one wanted to get a count of all records in "fixed" status or later, you'd just do a sum on the flag column.

Comment: Note that I have evolved in my thinking and would not necessarily recommend a Kimball-style approach to anything. However, as you will hear that from the majority of data warehouse people, I'll leave the answer as is.